# pseudo-random pattern with fixed density and exclusion zone

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I wish to create a 2D set of N points (typically 1e2 - 1e4) in a square with the following constraints:

- there should be a minimal distance between all points (hard core exclusion zone)
- the number of points filling the square is given in advance (or a close estimate), as I want to obtain a fixed density (I can adjust a little the size of the square afterwards if necessary).
- the pattern should be reasonably "random"
- a fast solution is preferred

I used rStrauss in the package spatstat before, but i could never figure out how to reliably obtain a given number of points, and quite often the function would stall my machine for 10 minutes, presumably because the task was too hard. I'm guessing there may be a more suitable function for this.

```
## regular grid of 1e2 points in [-10, 10]^2
xy = expand.grid(x=seq(-10, 10, length=10), y=seq(-10, 10, length=10))
N = NROW(xy)
```

EDIT: as suggested in the answer

```
xyr = rSSI(r=0.1, N, win = owin(c(-10,10),c(-10,10)), N)
plot(xyr)
```

[image: pp]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rSSI`, also in the spatstat package, takes care of your issues, except possibly the speed, depending on your standards. It has a hardcore inhibition distance, and will hit a target number of points (or give up trying--you can set the threshold for giving up), and the placements are random. I don't think it's particularly fast, but I was able to create `1e6` points in the unit square with an inhibition distance of `1e-4` in about 30 seconds. The speed and success rate will depend heavily on your inhibition distance relative to the number of points.

Comment: Interesting problem. I'd be curious about what is the most efficient algorithm, in general. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 2):

Mostly as an excuse to learn some more about Rcpp, here is my attempt at a little function to do this:

```
require(inline)
require(Rcpp)

randPoints = cxxfunction(signature(r_n='int', r_mindist='float', r_maxiter='int'), body = 
' 
  using namespace std;

  int n = as<int> (r_n);
  float mindist = as<float> (r_mindist);
  int maxiter = as<int> (r_maxiter);

  RNGScope scope;
  bool tooclose;
  int iter;
  NumericVector rands (2);
  NumericMatrix points (n, 2);
  NumericVector dist (2);

  for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    iter = 0;
    do {
      iter++;
      tooclose = false;
      rands = runif(2, 0, 1);
      for (int idist=0; idist < i; idist++) {
        dist = rands - points(idist, _);
        dist = dist * dist;
        if (sqrt(accumulate(dist.begin(), dist.end(), 0.0)) < mindist) {
          tooclose = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    } while (tooclose & iter < maxiter);
    if (iter == maxiter) {
      Rprintf("%d iterations reached\\nOnly %d points found\\n", maxiter, i+1);
      break;
    }
    NumericMatrix::Row target(points, i);
    target = rands;
  }

  return(wrap(points));
'
, plugin='Rcpp')
```

Then you can use it like:

```
> x = randPoints(1000, 0.05, 10000)
10000 iterations reached
Only 288 points found
```

And here is the plot:

```
x = x[as.logical(rowMeans(x != 0)), ]
dev.new(width=4, height=4)
plot(x)
```

[image]